# How to convert Dask Object columns into decimal columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, dask, dask-dataframe

I have this function

```py
def dec(x):
    """Convert to Decimal and remove exponent and trailing zeros"""
    if not x:
        return Decimal(0)
    if not isinstance(x, Decimal):
        x = Decimal(str(x))
    return x.quantize(Decimal(1)) if x == x.to_integral() else x.normalize()
```

In pandas I would do

```
df['price'].apply(dec)
```

However, dask doesn't support this so what is another way to convert a column into the decimal type?

Comment: The question is already answered here:
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Dask DataFrame does support apply, and it'll work well for your example:

```
ds = dd.from_pandas(s, npartitions=2)
ds.apply(dec).compute()
```

In general though, I'd suggest using `map_paritions` like Sultan has demonstrated.

You can also check out this blog: [Parallelize pandas apply() and map() with Dask DataFrame](https://coiled.io/blog/parallelize-pandas-apply-and-map-with-dask-dataframe/) that discusses these functions in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `dask` dataframe is called `ddf`, the `.map_partitions` should resolve it:

```py
def pandas_wrap(df):
   df['new_price'] = df['price'].apply(dec)
   # potentially some other pandas code
   return df

ddf = ddf.map_partitions(pandas_wrap)
```